# Merge Raster Images in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am creating maps of various section of the Appalachian Trail.

I have approximately 40 GeoTiffs of STRM data that I would like to merge together.

As I understand these images each gradation is related to an elevation so 0 is 0 meters above sea level and 200 would be 200 meters above sea level. Correct me if I am wrong.

In the individual GeoTiffs, the lowest value that I have is 0 and the highest value is 1324.

When I merge the files the range goes from 0-746.

How would I go about merging them to make sure they all come together fine

Comment: Are you sure that the highest value is 746? Did you check histogram? What kind of data type is the output (8, 16 bits, float)?

Comment: QGIS automatically stretches the data based on the histogram (*Cumulative count cut*). May that be the case? Try Layer Properties -> Style -> Contrast Enhancement and choose **No Enhancement**.

Answer (score 3):

For best results when merging DEM data, I use SAGA's "Mosaic Raster Layers" tool which can be accessed via the Processing Toolbox (NB: make sure it's set to Advanced Interface).

There is quite a lot of functionality with this tool, however as a good starting point you can go with the following key parameters detailed in the screenshot:

[image]
For blending distance I recommend measuring your overlaps (if any) with the measuring tool first.

For cell size stick with the original spatial resolution of the input images assuming they are all of the same resolution.

Comment: Do you like that better than GRASS i.image.mosaic ?